# Are Spring XD processors single-threaded?

Tags: thread-safety, spring-xd

When writing the transformer method of a Spring XD processor, do I have any guarantee that the code will be executed in a single thread?

If I understood correctly the architecture section of the Spring XD Guide (version 1.2.1), DIRT will deploy at most one copy of a module for any stream at any given time, am I correct? And if that's the case, does that mean I can write the code without worrying to make it reentrant?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No guarantee - it depends on the message bus deployment properties - e.g. with a `RabbitMessageBus` you can set the concurrency to > 1.

Yes, there's one instance of the module, but you can have multiple threads in that instance.